# Rails: checking modified fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, I've generated scaffold called 'item'

I'd like to check which fields of the item are modified. and I've tried two possible attempts, those're not work tho.

First Attempt!

```
def edit
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item_before_update = @item.dup
end

def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  # compare @item_before_update and @item here, but @item_before_update is NIL !!!
end
```

Second Attempt!
I looked for the way passing data from view to controller and I couldn't.
*edit.html.erb*

```
<% @item_before_update = @item.dup %> # I thought @item_before_update can be read in update method of item controller. But NO.
<% params[:item_before_update] = @item.dup %> # And I also thought params[:item_before_update] can be read in update mothod of item controller. But AGAIN NO

<% form_for(@item) do |f| %>
# omitted
<% end %>
```

Please let me know how to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Attributes that have changes that have not been persisted will respond true to `changed?`

```
@item.title_changed? #=> true
```

You can get an array of changed attributes by using `changed`

```
@item.changed #=> ['title']
```

For your `#update` action, you need to use `attributes=` to change the object, then you can use `changed` and `changed?` before persisting:

```
def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.attributes = params[:item]
  @item.changed #=> ['title']
  ... do stuff
  @item.save
end
```

Comment: This is cool, but not work in update action of the item controller. What's wrong?

Comment: I've added an example update method. The reason it wasn't working is that you retrieved @item from the database, so it was not changed. You then need to update it with your params from the submitted form, then you can get the `changed` status, and persist if you wish.

Comment: I think the above must be Rails 3.  In Rails 2, you can check if an attribute was changed like:  @item.title_changed?.  (See http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects)

Comment: Nope, `changed?` defined only for your model instance not for you attributes (i.e. integers, strings etc.). As of Rails 3.2.3 you still need `@object.attribute_changed?` in order to perform per attribute check. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html